# Enviar datos de impresión por el puerto COM

Tags: php, c#, impresión

En `C#` y también me gustaría saberlo para `php` para futuras actualizaciones. Quisiera enviar información de impresión por el **puerto COM1**

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo abrir el puerto y cómo sería la mejor manera de enviar información por ahí?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C#

Puedes usar la clase [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

Para escuchar el puerto debes suscribir el evento `DataReceived`

```
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);


private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort serialPort= (SerialPort)sender;
    string datos = serialPort.ReadExisting();
    //todo        
}
```

Y para mandar datos podemos usar `Write`

```
byte[] codigo = new byte[] { 1,2,3 };

MySerialPort.Write(codigo, 0, codigo.Length);
```

Aunque hace muchos años que no uso este puerto

---

Debemos de cerrar el puerto tras completar nuestras tareas

```
serialPort.Close();
```

Y con `serialPort.IsOpen` podemos verificar que nuestra conexion sigue abierta

Comment: @GilbertoAsuaje Hice una edición

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias amigo !

Answer (score 1):

Otra posible solución es usar Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll

Es la librería que usa (o usaba) el migrador de VB6 a VB.NET para simular los accesos directos al buffer de la impresora.